# How to calculate total time of daily mobile use in iOS Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I want to calculate total hours of mobile use per day. I already implemented the code below but still not getting any proper response of total hours. So, please suggest another way to find total hours of daily mobile use.

Import two file:-

```
#import <mach/mach.h>
#import <assert.h>

-(float) cpu_usage
{
    kern_return_t kr;
    task_info_data_t tinfo;
    mach_msg_type_number_t task_info_count;

    task_info_count = TASK_INFO_MAX;
    kr = task_info(mach_task_self(), TASK_BASIC_INFO, (task_info_t)tinfo, &task_info_count);
    if (kr != KERN_SUCCESS) {
        return -1;
    }

    task_basic_info_t      basic_info;
    thread_array_t         thread_list;
    mach_msg_type_number_t thread_count;

    thread_info_data_t     thinfo;
    mach_msg_type_number_t thread_info_count;

    thread_basic_info_t basic_info_th;
    uint32_t stat_thread = 0; // Mach threads

    basic_info = (task_basic_info_t)tinfo;

    // get threads in the task
    kr = task_threads(mach_task_self(), &thread_list, &thread_count);
    if (kr != KERN_SUCCESS) {
        return -1;
    }

    if (thread_count > 0)

        NSLog(@"Count::%u",thread_count);

    NSDate *methodStart = [NSDate date];
    NSDate *methodFinish = [NSDate date];
    NSTimeInterval executionTime = [methodFinish timeIntervalSinceDate:methodStart];

    NSLog(@"executionTime = %f", executionTime);

    NSString *sTr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u",thread_count];
    lbl_smartphone.text = sTr;

    stat_thread += thread_count;

    long tot_sec = 0;
    long tot_usec = 0;
    float tot_cpu = 0;
    int j;

    for (j = 0; j < (int)thread_count; j++)
    {
        thread_info_count = THREAD_INFO_MAX;
        kr = thread_info(thread_list[j], THREAD_BASIC_INFO,
                         (thread_info_t)thinfo, &thread_info_count);
        if (kr != KERN_SUCCESS) {
            return -1;
        }

        basic_info_th = (thread_basic_info_t)thinfo;

        if (!(basic_info_th->flags & TH_FLAGS_IDLE)) {
            tot_sec = tot_sec + basic_info_th->user_time.seconds + basic_info_th->system_time.seconds;
            tot_usec = tot_usec + basic_info_th->user_time.microseconds + basic_info_th->system_time.microseconds;
            tot_cpu = tot_cpu + basic_info_th->cpu_usage / (int)TH_USAGE_SCALE * 100.0;
            NSLog(@"Total CPU use:: %f",tot_cpu);
        }

    } // for each thread

    kr = vm_deallocate(mach_task_self(), (vm_offset_t)thread_list, thread_count * sizeof(thread_t));
    assert(kr == KERN_SUCCESS);

    return tot_cpu;
}
```

> I get thread count from above code but I want to get total hours mobile use per day

Comment: What is mobile use per day for you exactly?

Comment: I want to get mobile usage in hours per day from any iPhones.

Comment: What do you define as usage, phone on, phone moved, etc? If you can answer yourself this questions you know what you could do. This is not trivial as it might look. Not all data will be provided by the OS.

Comment: I want to get total time of the mobile screen ON

Comment: Without breaking App Store guidelines and accessing private frameworks you will not be able to get the total amount of time that the screen was on. You will only be allowed to measure the amount of time the user has the screen on, while your app is running in the foreground.

Comment: The former poster is correct, you can also get the device uptime, but that is more than the screen time.